# Compare indicator value with historical value X candles ago

Tags: pine-script

My goal is to compare the current bars CCI level against the last 10 candles and if it is lower than any/all of them, mark the current bar with *barcolor*. 
This would be done by running a CCI inside of the indicator like this:

```
MyCCI = cci(close, 10)
```

Pine does not allow *barcolor* inside of "if" statements and there seems to be no logical way to compare two values. Am I missing a more obvious way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the function `lowest()`. This function takes two arguments: the series and the length in bars (integer).

The `if` statement isn't needed because the true/false logic can be done directly inside the `barcolor()` function. `MyCCI == lowest_cci` compares the CCI for current bar to the lowest for the last 10 bars.

```
//@version=3
study("Lowest CCI", overlay=true)
MyCCI = cci(close, 10)
lowest_cci = lowest(MyCCI, 10)
// if current CCI is lowest, change bar to white, else change to blue
barcolor(MyCCI == lowest_cci ? white : blue)
```

Here's how the script affects the chart. All the white bars match your condition. Hope this helps!
[image: changing bar color with pine script]